# Creating or adapting a SQL Server database from a scripts folder

Tags: sql-server, database, version-control, database-project

I currently have a source controlled directory which represents a DB (i.e. it has create scripts for table, stored procedures, etc).  This is currently synchronized with an actual DB using RedGate SQL Compare software. Is it possible to (possibly using a standard MS database project) to script these tables to create a new (or adapt an old) database without using the same RedGate software?

I've tried creating a new MS database project, but it seems to want to run from an existing DB, or have files added one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a new database project, then use the [Import Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh864423%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) feature to populate the project with the objects from your database server.

Comment: I did consider that, but I wanted to be able to do this without creating a database first.

Comment: From your post it sounds like you already have a database created.

Comment: I think Keith is on the right track. Create the database locally from your scripts and import from there into a project or import directly from your already existing database. If you can access the existing database, you should be able to easily create the project from that. I would also consider migrating to SSDT instead of VS DB Projects if you have the option.